# Ruby on rails - pass params from db to environment config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

im using a gem for a sms service, and i have to put the params in the specific environment config file.

All is ok with static params, but if i call this params from a db, starting the webrick i have an error: 
(ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)

this is my original code in development.rb

```
Skuby.setup do |config|
config.method = 'send_sms_classic' #default
config.username = 'myusername'
config.password = 'mypassword'
config.password = Setting.where(campo: 'skebby_password').valore
config.sender_string = 'company' #optional
config.sender_number = '39123456790' #optional
config.charset = 'UTF-8' #skebby default is ISO-8859-1
```

end

changing something, like:

```
config.password = Setting.where(campo: 'skebby_password').valore
```

it goes down!

How can i fix?

Comment: could u provide your `database.yml`? did you create a database and run all the migrations?

Comment: the db config is ok, but seems this environment file is called befor the db-connection

Comment: default: &default
   #adapter: mysql
   adapter: mysql2
   timeout: 5000
   encoding: utf8

test:
   <<: *default
   database: ruby_assistenza
   username: ruby
   password: password
   host: 10.0.0.1
   port: 3306
   #flags:
   # - -COMPRESS
   # - FOUND_ROWS
   # - MULTI_STATEMENTS
   #secure_auth: false

development:
   <<: *default
   database: ruby_assistenza
   username: ruby
   password: password
   host: 192.168.1.42
   port: 3306
   #flags:
   # - -COMPRESS
   # - FOUND_ROWS
   # - MULTI_STATEMENTS
   #secure_auth: false

...........

Comment: did you try to move that `skuby.setup` lines out of environment file to something like `config/initializers/skuby.rb` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think it's ok to do this in your `config/environment`. I would think that such would be better suited for your `config/initializers`, within your initializer, your db connection is already setup.

BTW, if you're using different parameters for your environments, I think you should rather use a configuration file, which would set your params per environment and you could then use that.